# Как заменить строку в pdf файле с помощью node js?

Tags: node.js, pdf

Есть файл пдф, когда я открываю его через notepad первая строчка начинается с %PDF-1.4

Если я её меняю через notepad++ и сохраняю, то все окей.

Если же я заменяю версию скриптом на nodejs то файл рушится и становится не читаемым.

Использую этот код. Но сохраненный таким способом файл перестает открываться.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('C:/pdf/1.pdf', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var formatted = data.replace(/%PDF-1.4/g, '%PDF-1.5');
    fs.writeFile('C:/pdf/1.pdf', formatted, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Как все-таки можно изменить строку в пдф используя nodejs, чтобы не портился файл?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Использую этот код. Но сохраненный таким способом файл перестает открываться. 

var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('C:/pdf/1.pdf', 'utf8', function (err,data) {

  var formatted = data.replace(/%PDF-1.4/g, '%PDF-1.5');

 fs.writeFile('C:/pdf/1.pdf', formatted, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
 });
});

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте этот код в свой вопрос

Comment: вместо `utf8`, попробуйте написать `base64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет необходимости читать и переписывать весь файл только для того чтобы заменить первые несколько байт.

Для решения этой задачи "в лоб" можно использовать базовый инструмент nodejs - [потоки](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/stream.html). Создаём readable stream, читающий первые байты. Передаём в transform stream, выполняющий замену. И пишем в файл c 0-вой позиции с помощью write stream.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Transform } = require('stream');

const filepath = 'C:/pdf/1.pdf';

fs.createReadStream(filepath, { start: 0, end: 7 })
    .pipe(new Transform({
        transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            this.push(chunk.toString().replace(/PDF-1\.4/, 'PDF-1.5'));
            callback();
        }
    }))
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath, { start: 0, flags: 'a' }));
```

В качестве задания для саморазвития можете добавить потокам обработчики ошибок.